# How could Buzz come to know about Al's Toy Barn?

Tags: plot-explanation, toy-story

After the chicken man stole Woody from Andy's house, Buzz somehow discovered he was taken to the Al's Toy Barn from the numberplate of the car. I could not understand that part. How could he discover it using a toy?

**Screenshot:-**

[image: How's he doing this]

Comment: I didn't even understood that scene, +1 for raising it here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is common for people with [vanity license plates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanity_plate) to remove vowels in order to create longer phrases that fit on the plate.

In this case:

> LZ = als
>   TY = toy
>   BRN = barn

Comment: It also helps if you have a little background on the Speak & Spell toy, and understand It's purpose : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speak_%26_Spell_(toy)